# Getting Slavnov-Taylor identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral

Let's have generating functional in path integral form for gauge $SU(n)$ theory with interaction:
$$
\tag 1 Z[J] = \int DB D\bar{\Psi}D\Psi D\bar{c}Dc e^{iS}.
$$
Here
$$
S = S_{YM}(B, \partial B) + S_{M}(\Psi , D\Psi) + S_{ghosts} + \int d^{4}x \left[-\frac{1}{2\alpha}(\partial_{\mu}B^{\mu}_{a})^{2} + \sum_{\varphi}(J_{\varphi} \cdot \varphi ) \right],
$$
$$
L_{ghosts} = \bar{c}^{a}(\delta_{ab}\partial^{2} + gc_{acb}B_{\mu}^{c}\partial^{\mu})c^{b}.
$$

I want to get Slavnov-Taylor identities for nonabelian case by using the fact that $(1)$ doesn't change under translation substitution $\varphi \to \varphi^{\omega} = \varphi + \delta_{\omega}\varphi $. In abelian case identity which acts role of Slavnov-Taylor identity (it shows that full propagator of EM field has transverse structure) can be derived by using the result of invariance of $\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta J_{\mu}^{A}(x)} Z[J]\right)_{J =0}$ under sets of transformations
$$
\Psi \to \Psi^{\omega} \approx \Psi (1 + i\omega ), \quad \bar{\Psi} \to \bar{\Psi}^{\omega}\approx \bar{\Psi}(1 - i\omega ), \quad A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu}^{\omega} \approx A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}\omega .
$$
The result is
$$
\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \omega (z)}\frac{\delta}{J_{\mu}^{A}(x)} Z[J]\right)_{J, \omega =0} = \int \prod_{\varphi}D \varphi \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{\mu}}\delta (x - z) - \frac{i}{\alpha}A_{\mu}(x)\partial^{2}\partial^{\nu}A_{\nu}(z)\right) e^{iS} = 0
$$
(you can read about it, for example, on page 99 [here](http://www.itp.phys.ethz.ch/research/qftstrings/archive/11FSQFT2/script.pdf)).

But when I have tried to get Slavnov-Taylor identity (I mean [this one](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Slavnov-Taylor_identities); I need to variate it with respect on $J_{\mu}^{b}$ and then set it to zero) bu using the invariance of $(1)$ under transformations
$$
B_{\mu}^{a} \to (B_{\mu}^{a})^{\omega} = B_{\mu}^{a} + g\omega^{c}B_{\mu}^{b}g_{cba} + \partial_{\mu}\omega_{a}, \quad \Psi \to ... ,
$$
but I haven't got it. Is this way incorrect?

Comment: The identity on the link you mentioned is for pure Yang Mills, without matter. To derive this use the BRST invariance of the partition function.